# How to stop Postfix from forwarding SPAM without blocking local users' SPAM?

Tags: postfix, spam, mail-forwarding

Some of my users have aliases in `/etc/postfix/virtual` that forward to other providers (mostly gmail).  I believe that the fact that all mail is forwarded (even SPAM) is causing reputation issues for my IP.  How can I block forwarding of mail that SpamAssasin says are SPAM, while still delivering SPAM to local (non-forward) users?

Comment: Maybe check https://aikar.co/2014/09/05/filtering-spam-forwarding-email-postfixspamassassin/